# Begin Rescue not catching error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, error-handling, rescue

I'm using some ruby code wrapped in a begin - rescue block but somehow it manages to still crash.

the block of code looks like this:

```
# Retrieve messages from server
def get_messages
  @connection.select('INBOX')
  @connection.uid_search(['ALL']).each do |uid|
    msg = @connection.uid_fetch(uid,'RFC822').first.attr['RFC822']
    begin
      process_message(msg)
      add_to_processed_folder(uid) if @processed_folder
    rescue
       handle_bogus_message(msg)
    end
    # Mark message as deleted 
    @connection.uid_store(uid, "+FLAGS", [:Seen, :Deleted])
  end
end
```

Given this code i would assume that if **process_message** or **add_to_processed_folder** could not execute then rescue would kick in and call **handle_bogus_message**. That being said I'm running this code in a production environment and  sometimes when i "get" an email message (this is run from a rake task) it dies with a **SyntaxError**.

For a look at the error message check out http://pastie.org/1028479  and not that **process_message** that it is referring to is the same **process_message** above. Is there any reason why **begin** - **rescue** won't catch this exception?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

`rescue` without a parameter just rescues exceptions that inherit from `StandardError`. To rescue a `SyntaxError` use `rescue SyntaxError`.

To rescue all exceptions you would use `rescue Exception`, but note that that's a bad idea (which is why it's not the default behavior of `rescue`) as explained [here](http://www.mikeperham.com/2012/03/03/the-perils-of-rescue-exception/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048173/why-is-it-bad-style-to-rescue-exception-e-in-ruby). Especially this part:

> Rescuing Interrupt prevents the user from using CTRLC to exit the program.
>
> Rescuing SignalException prevents the program from responding correctly to signals. It will be unkillable except by kill -9.

Comment: The reason `rescue` doesn't rescue `Exception`s by default is that they're usually regarded as too severe to rescue.

Comment: This still didn't catch SyntaxError for some reason. I am adding extra logging before re-raising the exception. The actual problem on customer side is that they get unescaped RegExp and I get SyntaxError when trying to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3):

`rescue` without any parameter accepts exceptions raised by StandardError class. Your error type is SyntaxError which is inherited from a different class called ScriptError. All these error classes are subclasses of Exception class. So as sepp2k suggested use `rescue Exception` to catch all kinds of exceptions.