# Can't rescue YAML.load exception

Tags: ruby, exception, yaml

I'm trying to handle loading invalid YAML data in Ruby, but seem to be unable to rescue exceptions raised by psych.

This is some example code to demonstrate the issue I'm having:

```
require 'yaml'
begin
    YAML.load('&*%^*')
rescue
    puts "Rescued"
end
```

And the exception:

```
# ruby test.rb
/usr/lib64/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:203:in `parse': (<unknown>): did not find expected alphabetic or numeric character while scanning an anchor at line 1 column 1 (Psych::SyntaxError)
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:203:in `parse_stream'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:151:in `parse'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:127:in `load'
    from test.rb:3:in `<main>'
```

Comment: On a side note, I'd suggest you don't use `YAML.load` with any user expected data, given the fact all the recent rails YAML and JSON related vulnerabilities that allowed a malicious user to do Remote Execution Exploits.

Comment: Did you get any solution for this issue?? other than catching exception..

Comment: @shajin I did what is in the accepted solution, `rescue SyntaxError`, and not all of `Exception`. Not the greatest, but better than having to rescue everything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [Begin Rescue not catching error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3168160/begin-rescue-not-catching-error). It is possible to rescue Syntax Errors, but not recommended. This is why you need to jump through the extra hoop of typing "`rescue SyntaxError`".

Comment: Ah, my google fu failed me :-(. Thanks, that explains it rather well.

Answer (score 9):

The inheritance for `SyntaxError` is:

```
SyntaxError < ScriptError < Exception
```

`rescue` without parameters only catches `StandardError` which is a subclass of `Exception`:

```
StandardError < Exception
```

So, if you want to catch the Syntax errors from `Yaml.load`, you must `rescue SyntaxError => e` or to catch all errors using `rescue Exception => e`.

Comment: Also [`Psych::SyntaxError` is a subclass of `::SyntaxError`](https://github.com/tenderlove/psych/blob/v1.3.4/lib/psych/syntax_error.rb#L2) which is why this applies to this case. (Although subclassing `::SyntaxError` does seem like an odd decision).