# How to rescue Psych Yaml exceptions?

Tags: ruby, yaml

This is actually 3 part question:

1. What are all the exceptions Psych throws?
2. How do you know which ones they are when documentation doesn't bother to list them?
3. Sample code to catch all possible YAML.load_file exceptions?

I wouldn't ask for no 3 but this question suggests I will encounter wierd issues:
[Can't rescue YAML.load exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14676656/cant-rescue-yaml-load-exception)

Based on this question 
[How to know what exceptions to rescue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34443407/how-to-know-what-exceptions-to-rescue)

I got:

```
Psych::Exception
      Psych::BadAlias
      Psych::DisallowedClass
      Psych::SyntaxError
```

But when I try to catch that code still fails

```
irb(main):002:0> begin
irb(main):003:1* YAML.load_file('test_file_does_not_exist')
irb(main):004:1> rescue Psych::Exception
irb(main):005:1> puts $!.message
irb(main):006:1> end
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - test
    from /home/marko/.gem/ruby/2.3.1/gems/psych-2.1.0/lib/psych.rb:474:in `initialize'
    from /home/marko/.gem/ruby/2.3.1/gems/psych-2.1.0/lib/psych.rb:474:in `open'
    from /home/marko/.gem/ruby/2.3.1/gems/psych-2.1.0/lib/psych.rb:474:in `load_file'
    from (irb):3
    from /home/marko/.rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

I am looking for ways to catch all of that nonsense. Regardless for the reason of failure, I want to catch it and display a message before it falls back to main exception handling code.

Microsoft, which I don't particularly like, shows all exceptions for every class they ever wrote. Example:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b9skfh7s(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

## Psych exceptions

One way to check would be :

```
exceptions_before = ObjectSpace.each_object(Class).select{|klass| klass < Exception}
require 'yaml'
exceptions_after  = ObjectSpace.each_object(Class).select{|klass| klass < Exception}
```

It might miss Exceptions that are dynamically generated. Still, here's the difference between the 2, and their ancestors :

```
(exceptions_after - exceptions_before).each do |yaml_exception|
  p yaml_exception.ancestors
end

# [Psych::SyntaxError, Psych::Exception, RuntimeError, StandardError, Exception, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
# [Psych::DisallowedClass, Psych::Exception, RuntimeError, StandardError, Exception, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
# [Psych::BadAlias, Psych::Exception, RuntimeError, StandardError, Exception, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
# [Psych::Exception, RuntimeError, StandardError, Exception, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
# [StringScanner::Error, StandardError, Exception, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

It seems that `Psych::Exception` and `StringScanner::Error` cover all the exceptions thrown by `Psych`.

## Other exceptions

Anything could go wrong anywhere. Still, the most common exception will be :

```
Errno::ENOENT
```

if your `.yml` isn't found. You could either rescue the exception or just check that `File.exist?` before reading the yaml file.

IMHO, you shouldn't try to rescue every exception.

Even though it looks like you're looking for `rescue => e` or even `rescue Exception => e`, it's [not a good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048173/why-is-it-bad-style-to-rescue-exception-e-in-ruby).

Comment: What about the ERRNO::SOMETHING when you `YAML.load_file` that doesn't exist?

Comment: What about the sytax error when you don't close the quotes around the filename string? :) Basically anything can go wrong while loading a file. I understood the question as referring to Psych specific exceptions.

Comment: Sorry for wasting your time, I have just editted the question.

Comment: No offense meant, and you didn't waste my time. I just wanted to make a point, possibly too aggressively, though.

Comment: Upvoted. Thank you I wouldn't catch the StringScanner::Error and I like the code you used to discover exceptions. Still it feels weird as if you can never be sure that caught them all.

Comment: I'm not sure you could be sure to catch them all in any language. Surely not in Ruby, given its extremly dynamic nature.

Comment: You may want to mention that the specific exception for loading a nonexistent file is `ScriptError::LoadError`.

Comment: @MattSchuchard : As I wrote in the answer : `Anything could go wrong anywhere`. LoadError would be thrown when `require` cannot find another ruby file. It doesn't have much to do with YAML IMHO.

Comment: `YAML.load_file` throws `Errno::ENOENT` with a nonexistent file. Or did I misunderstand your comment?